# My .net 3.5 Web Services work on Server 2008 R2 but do not work on Server 2012 R2, what gives?

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2012-r2

I've be searching and pulling my hair out,but cannot seem to find a solution.
I have a WCF web service application that works fine on Server 2008 R2 under IIS. I now have a new server with Server 2012 R2 on it and I cannot get the web services to fully run under IIS.

When I access the web service *.svc file from the Visual Studio 2008 WCF Test Client it loads up and displays all the web services. However if I try to make a call to any of them it returns an error as shown in the image below.

[WCF Test Client Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTu6l.png)

If you can't see the image: this is the text of the error returned in the Test Client.

Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at iAxRegService.GetSchoolInfo(String DatabaseKey, String OptCommand)
   at iAxRegServiceClient.GetSchoolInfo(String DatabaseKey, String OptCommand)

Again: If I turn the WCF client to point over to the same service on my Server 2008 R2 box, I get the proper response returned. So what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Seems like I have turned on every option that other post have mentioned including svc handler mappings and MIME Types.

This is my first post, so if I need to provide any other information to help, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can now see why I got no response to the question. Everything in IIS and SQL is setup correctly. 
The problem was our App. It requires a authenticated user and the Web Service could not authenticate the public anonymous user, because we had never added that public user to the list of allowed users.
I think the biggest problem is that the WCF Test Client, just gave me that meaningless "Object Not set to an instance of an object" error.
Anyway, I just wanted to close this question out.